# Twitter boostrap modal not working in php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" />

  <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">  

        <button class="btn btn-default"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                +Add Question
                            </button></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">

  </div>
</div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't get the modal to open it seems so simple yet its giving a problem.

Please help

Comment: Are those `link` tags in the `head` or the `body`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `<script>` tag in order in include javascript files in your HTML page.

`<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

and

`<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Put them right before the body tag closes:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```